# How can I pass variables to different processes c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables

I have multiple processes running via fork() and data coming in from a TCP socket. Based on the a header of the data read in, I want to pass the data to a specific one of the multiple processes.

Is there any way to pass data to a specific process and are there any listeners I can use in that processes as to avoid an infinite waiting loop?

Comment: Why not create a thread each time? It doesn't mean you make a ton of threads if you use async

Comment: @IvanRubinson I agree, the very fact that the OP says that he wants to communicate with the processes screams that it should have been a thread and not a forked process.

Comment: I'm open to using threads as well; in that case is there a simple way to send data to specific threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is Interprocess Communication. This is platform dependent.

For Linux, I would recommend pseudo-terminals, or PIPEs. [Linux Interprocess Communcation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html)

There is a short example here to create a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) to a child process. You can use [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) to determine when there is data to be read in the child process.

However, as others have mentioned, you may be better served by multithreading than multiprocessing.

Comment: The general name for this topic is: 
**IPC** = Inter-Process Communication."  Google these terms *(and/or, search for them right here!),* and you will immediately see that there is a *lot* of "prior art" that can help you.  ## *(Furthermore,* you will find frameworks for building complete "RPC = Remote Procedure-Call" servers, such as the one that you appear now to be in the process of building from scratch!)  For instance, sally over to http://www.github.com and search for "C++ RPC server" . . . What you're doing has been done. Don't do it again. **:-)**